# How do I Recover a lost Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I created a Facebook app ad then inadvertently removed all admins (including myself) from the app. Now I can't manage it. Our website is still referencing the app id, and we are still posting comments using it, so I know it still exists in the system. I don't want to create a new app and lose all those comments. Is there a way to recover the app or move the apps' comments to a new app id?

Comment: I really want to know, how can you remove all the admins of an app? As of now facebook does not allow you to remove all the admins of an app. There should be atleast one admin for the app. Please ask any of the admins to add you.

Comment: Looking for that answer as well, I have the same problem, one app and no admin anymore

Comment: They don't allow YOU to delete all admins, but if facebook deletes an account for any reason, they don't stop if it's the only admin on an account.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this form to get access to Developer Operations staff that have been able to help me with similar requests.
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/1838825039720902

Also, if the app was deleted, it can often be restored via https://developers.facebook.com/appeal/

Answer (score 1):

If an application is deleted there is no way to recover it.  As far as removing all the admins from the application, this is not something the Admin console allows.  You should have been presented with this message when doing so ... "Must specify one developer with admin permissions." ...

Comment: Then is there any way to transfer comments from a "deleted" app (that is still receiving comments) to a new app id? We have thousands of comments that have been entered using the app id, and I'm afraid I will lose all of them if I simple switch to a new app. The app id seems to function just fine with the commenting mechanism, but I can't edit the app or reference it in any other way.